# Download .img file from given link using wget-module

Tags: python, web-scraping, download, wget

I am trying to download a file in python using the [wget module](https://pypi.org/project/wget/). The problem is, that the original file size is about 125mb, the file size of my download is just ~7kb

My code:

```
import wget
download_link = "https://dl.twrp.me/gauguin/twrp-3.5.2_10-0-gauguin.img"
wget.download(download_link)
```

Output:

```
100% [................................................................................] 6846 / 6846'twrp-3.5.2_10-0-gauguin.img'
```

File size:

```
francesco@francesco-ubuntu:~/Dokumente/GIT/python_adb$ ls -al twrp-3.5.2_10-0-gauguin.img 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 francesco francesco 6846 Feb  6 22:26 twrp-3.5.2_10-0-gauguin.img
```

Am I doing something wrong? Like I said, the original file size is ca 125mb, the file I downloaded around 7kb

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the contents of the downloaded file? When I load that URL in my browser, it goes to a web page where I'm invited to download the file. You'll probably need to set some headers.

Comment: @MattDMo I opened with nano and it seems like the content is .html text. Cant copy whole hmtl text here.

The beginning is: "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>........."

Comment: Did you put the URL into your browser?

Comment: It actualy fetches the download html page

Comment: @MattDMo yes, I can download the file with the url trough browser. But I want to download it trough python :(

Comment: Ok, so if you go to: https://dl.twrp.me/gauguin/twrp-3.5.2_10-0-gauguin.img there is a file to download. When I click on that link on the website, I can directly download it through my browser. When I right-click the link and copy the link, paste it in another tab, I can also download it. But when I use this exact link in "wget.download(LINK) it does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To correctly download the file, try to set `Referer` and `User-Agent` HTTP header (example with `requests` module):

```py
import requests


url = "https://dl.twrp.me/gauguin/twrp-3.5.2_10-0-gauguin.img"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:96.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/96.0",
    "Referer": "https://dl.twrp.me/gauguin/twrp-3.5.2_10-0-gauguin.img",
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
with open("twrp-3.5.2_10-0-gauguin.img", "wb") as f_out:
    f_out.write(r.content)
```

Download the file:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 134217728 feb  6 22:49 twrp-3.5.2_10-0-gauguin.img
```

Answer (score 1):

So i found the solution but using `request` library, but I think you will be able to fix your code.

The fix is easy, you just need to specify `Referer` header

```
Referer: https://dl.twrp.me/gauguin/twrp-3.5.2_10-0-gauguin.img
```

So, my code with `requests`

```
import requests

image_url = "https://dl.twrp.me/gauguin/twrp-3.5.2_10-0-gauguin.img"

headers = {
    "Referer": "https://dl.twrp.me/gauguin/twrp-3.5.2_10-0-gauguin.img",
}

img_data = requests.get(image_url, headers=headers).content
with open('image_name.img', 'wb') as handler:
    handler.write(img_data)
```